# Vscode terminal lags only during first run of program

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-signing, executionpolicy

Bought a new, more powerful Windows system and installed Vscode on it. To my surprise, running basic Cpp files was much more slow on it. After some investigation here are my observations about the issue -

1. The lag is very prominent on the **first run after compile** Or when ran from CodeRunner `cd "d:\cpp_primer\" ; if ($?) { g++ arr1.cpp -o arr1 } ; if ($?) { .\arr1 }` which is indirectly the same thing
2. From second time onwards, `.\arr1` showed output very fast.

My deduction is that it is related to checking the code signature. Some days ago, I read an article where MacOs was checking them very frequently even on Xcode scripts.

Coincidentally, while installing `Msys2` on this system, there was error like `running scripts is disabled on this system...` which was solved when I changed "ExecutionPolicy" of both "CurrentUser" and "LocalMachine" from `Undefined` to `RemoteSigned`.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you looked at the command: `g++` is the compile phase and that takes time

Comment: @rioV8 the same one line program compiled in a blink in intel gen3 comapred to 5 seconds on gen11

Comment: 11 is almost 4*3, that is what we call progress